# Matlab: Removing struct values via an index array

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a large struct (total) that I need to separate into 3 structs who's values are random selected from the original struct. I need a struct with 60% (trainingData), and two structs that are 20% each (testData & crossValData) but none of the values can overlap.

```
indexRand1 = zeros((size(total,1)*.2),1); % index of test data: 20%
indexRand2 = zeros((size(total,1)*.2),1); % index of cross validation data: 20%

for index_i = 1:size(indexRand1,1)
    temp1 = randi([1 size(total,1)],1,1); % get a random value from total
    temp2 = randi([1 size(total,1)],1,1); % get another random value from total

    while ismember(temp1,indexRand1) % make sure 1st value is not already in test data
        temp1 = randi([1 size(total,1)],1,1);
    end
    indexRand1(index_i,1) = temp1; % add 1st value to test data

    while ismember(temp2,indexRand1) % make sure 2nd value is not already in test data
        temp2 = randi([1 size(total,1)],1,1);
        while ismember(temp2,indexRand2) % or cross validation data
            temp2 = randi([1 size(total,1)],1,1);
        end
    end
    indexRand2(index_i,1) = temp2; % add 2nd value to cross validation data
end
indexRand3 =[indexRand1;indexRand2]; % index of test and cross validation data 

testData = total(indexRand1,:); % use index to get test data
crossValData = total(indexRand2,:); % use index to get cross validation data
total(indexRand3,1) = []; % remove test and cross validation data
trainingData = total; % save training data to new name
```

My problem comes at 'total(indexRand3,1) = []; % remove test and cross validation data' the error I get is 'A null assignment can have only one non-colon index.' How do I remove values from a struct using an index? (or how do you separate a struct randomly into 3 unequal structs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making this problem much harder than it needs to be. A more Matlab-y solution seems to be:

```
%Make some test data
%    (Well, I guess you already have data. I need data to test with) 
total(1000).sampleData = 1

%Determine the number of elements in each derived set
nTraining = round(numel(total)*0.6);
nTest     = round(numel(total)*0.2);
nCrossVal = numel(total) - nTest - nTraining;

%Create a random order vector
ixsRandomOrder = randperm(numel(total));

%Use the random order vector to create distinct, derived sets
testData     = total(ixsRandomOrder(                    (1:nTest)     ));
trainingData = total(ixsRandomOrder(nTest +             (1:nTraining) ));
crossValData = total(ixsRandomOrder(nTest + nTraining + (1:nCrossVal) ));
```